# How can I temporarily disable localhost access to a certain port?

Tags: networking

I am developing a web application in Java, which is served by a Tomcat container on port 80. Another CLI application is connecting to the web application. I want to test if this CLI application is capable of reconnecting when the connection is dropped unexpectedly and if the web application is cleaning up correctly.

When stopping (`sudo service stop tomcat8`) or killing (`kill -9 <pid>`) Tomcat, the connection is dropped in a standard fashion. That is, the CLI application receives a `BYE` frame from the web application. I want to test what happens when there is a timeout, when there is a sudden drop of connection.

Is it possible to disable access on the localhost network to port 80 in such a way that neither the web application or the client have time to send their `BYE` frames?

Comment: If you close the port with `iptables` on the server (both incoming and outgoing), neither party will be able to properly close the connection. Packets will be stopped by the kernel.

Comment: Can this also be done if the server and the client are both the same machine? I am doing everything on `localhost` for testing and development.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but reasonably certain that packets from client to server (and v.v.) on the same host actually are sent to and received from the network interface, and therefore being stopped by INPUT DROP and OUTPUT DROP `iptables` rules. So the answer is yes.

Comment: Let me add these comments as an answer, including the proper `iptables` rules, and if it works, please accept it.

Comment: Sure, good idea!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `iptables` on the server, to stop it from sending packets to the client and from receiving packets from it:

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 80 -j DROP
```

will prevent the server from reaching the client; and

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP
```

will prevent the client from reaching the server. `sport` stands for source port and `dport` for destination port.

This is completely independent from the `tomcat` server process, and it will look (to the client and the server) as if the connection was suddenly interrupted. I am reasonably sure this will work even if client and server are on the same host.

See what rules are currently in place with:

```
sudo iptables -L
```

Remove all existing rules with:

```
sudo iptables -F
```